# Add a string with doublequotes to a variable?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a string like `"Research Expenses: Itemize and follow <a href=" http://www.borenawards.org/boren_fellowship/budget.html" target="_blank">budget guidelines</a>(maximum $3,000)"`

I want to assign that value to a sting variable.

```
string value= Research Expenses: Itemize and follow <a href=" http://www.borenawards.org/boren_fellowship/budget.html" 
target="_blank">budget guidelines</a>(maximum $3,000);
```

My need is that whatever string is passed to it I have to display the content inside a doublequotes .how to add the doublequotes?

I want to display string like `"Research Expenses: Itemize and follow <a href=" http://www.borenawards.org/boren_fellowship/budget.html" target="_blank">budget guidelines</a>(maximum $3,000)"`.please help me

Answer (score 1):

Hi there you can use escape sequence like:

```
string value= "Research Expenses: Itemize and follow <a href=" http://www.borenawards.org/boren_fellowship/budget.html" 
target="_blank">budget guidelines</a>(maximum $3,000)";
```

you can use another alternative thing by removeing double quotes and replace them with single quotes, at the end they will work fine: Example:

```
string value= "Research Expenses: Itemize and follow <a href=' http://www.borenawards.org/boren_fellowship/budget.html' 
target='_blank'>budget guidelines</a>(maximum $3,000)";
```

Your got both choices, and choice is yours.

Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can escape the double quotes if you want them to be included in the variable value, like so:

```
string str =  "Research Expenses: Itemize and follow <a href=\" http://www.borenawards.org/boren_fellowship/budget.html\" target=\"_blank\">budget guidelines</a>(maximum $3,000)";
```

[Demo](http://rextester.com/JFIB45754)

Answer (score 0):

In your string replace " with \"

Answer (score 0):

2 possibilities:

- Escape the inner " with the character \

`"Research Expenses: Itemize and follow <a href=\"http://www.borenawards.org/boren_fellowship/budget.html\" target=\"_blank\">budget guidelines</a>(maximum $3,000)"`

- Use ' instead of " inside the string

`"Research Expenses: Itemize and follow <a href='http://www.borenawards.org/boren_fellowship/budget.html' target='_blank'>budget guidelines</a>(maximum $3,000)"`

Answer (score 0):

string value= @"Research Expenses: Itemize and follow http://www.borenawards.org/boren_fellowship/budget.html"" target=""_blank"">budget guidelines(maximum $3,000)";